# Why external JS won't start?

Tags: javascript, onload

after to make some research I took the measures to guarantee that the JS will be loaded before trying to run it but... it won't work!

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            console.log('foo')
        }

        window.onload = function() {
            initialize();
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<html>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            initialize();
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js:

```
function initialize() {
    console.log('foo')
}
```

I don't get any error. It just doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Typo: You forgot the `</script>` for the first script in the second example. (Consequently the second `<script>` start tag and its body are ignored because it is part of a script element with a `src` attribute, and then the end tag for the second script ends the first script.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a closing script tag for the tag that is calling the external js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```